# GET запрос к endpoint "account" API криптобиржи Binance - 401 ошибка

Tags: api

Друзья, у меня не получается достучаться до endpoint account на API криптобиржи Binance. Получаю ошибку 401.

Ниже код. Функция подписывания работает корректно - проверил ее на примере с сайта биржи (https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html#user-content-signed-endpoint-security). 
Ключи тоже рабочие - подключил их к стороннему сервису Coinigy, там балансы видно.

```js
function BinanceTest(key,secret) {
/*var randnumber=Math.random()*500;
Utilities.sleep(randnumber);*/
var baseURL = "https://api.binance.com";
var completeURL = baseURL + "/api/v3/account";
var timestamp=new Date().getTime();
var payload = "timestamp="+timestamp;
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(payload, secret);
signature = signature.map(function(byte) {
  return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}).join('');
completeURL=completeURL+"?"+payload+"&signature="+signature;
var params = {
  'method': 'get',
  'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': key},
  'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};  
var response = fetchJSON(completeURL,params);
var servertime=fetchJSON("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time").serverTime;
return [servertime,timestamp,payload,signature,JSON.stringify(params),completeURL,response];

};


function fetchJSON (url) {
  var randnumber=Math.random()*3000;
  Utilities.sleep(randnumber);
  try {
    var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{muteHttpExceptions: true })
    } catch (exception) {
      Logger.log(url+": "+exception)
      return 'exception'
    } 
  if ('undefined' == typeof(json))
    return 'Error retrieving JSON data'
  
  if (json.getResponseCode() != 200)
    return json.getResponseCode()
    
  json = json.getContentText()
  if (json.length<=0)
    return 'JSON data was invalid'

  try {
    json = JSON.parse(json)
  } catch (exception) {
    Logger.log(url+" "+exception)
    return "err2"
  }
  if ('undefined' == typeof(json) || json == null)
    // return 'err'
  return 'Quote data was malformed JSON data'

  return json
}
```

Comment: Егорище, вы на русскоязычном сайте, переведите вопрос на русский язык :)

Comment: Выше дополнил код